# related to fail safe on linux suse machines

Tags: failsafe

Mechanism for swithing virtual ip if one server goes down to other server sharing same virtual ip as secondary ip

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out CARP or Heartbeat. I have experience of CARP and it works really well, Heartbeat is extremely popular as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Heartbeat](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Main_Page) has been working very well for me. In addition to IP addresses it can take care of other resources (processes, disk mounts etc) as well. And as 3molo said, CARP is a good one, too.